# npm start error on Starting in React Js App using cmd

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have created a Simple React App but when i am going to run it using cmd "npm start" it throws a bunch of errors. I also reinstall node js on my system and install many times node_modules. but everything gonna failed. I have also tried to run other projects on my system but I am getting almost same type of error.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp>npm start

> testapp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.8.0
3 info using node@v11.10.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~prestart: testapp@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: testapp@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.2 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.2 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.2 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.2 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp
10 silly lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot' ]
11 info lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
12 silly lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: -4058  signal: null
13 info lifecycle testapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: testapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
14 verbose stack spawn bash ENOENT
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
14 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:427:16)
14 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
15 verbose pkgid testapp@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp
17 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
18 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 verbose node v11.10.1
20 verbose npm  v6.8.0
21 error file bash
22 error path bash
23 error code ELIFECYCLE
24 error errno ENOENT
25 error syscall spawn bash
26 error testapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
26 error spawn bash ENOENT
27 error Failed at the testapp@1.0.0 start script.
27 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-06T12_08_45_188Z-debug.log

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\reactApp>
```

Comment: As it says `There is likely additional logging output above.` Look at the complete logs, there should be some other error

Comment: Please check I edit this question with complete log @Sachin Gupta

Comment: have you installed webpack-cli? if not, install it globally npm i webpack-cli -g

Comment: Everything i have installed. earlier all the react apps working on my system. but  i think some wrong configuration or another thing interrupt. I think if I create angular app it is also throw similar error. there is some "spawn bash ENOENT" error @vitomadio

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to either run `npm install` **in your project directory** or forgot to install `webpack-dev-server` before running `npm start`.

This issue on GitHub has pretty much the exact same error with the same solution: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/486

Comment: Everything i have installed. earlier all the react apps working on my system. but  i think some wrong configuration or another thing interrupt. I think if I create angular app it is also throw similar error. there is some "spawn bash ENOENT" error  @leroydev

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to this problem is to go to the following path first and apply these changes, and then restart your system and try again.

Control Panel>System and Security>System>Advance system setting>Enviroment variable and set system variables path C:\Windows\System32\ variable and restart your System.

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would work? Please keep in mind System32 is for Windows only and programs like NPM should NEVER install in System32.

Comment: so, I also use the 64-bit version ,when run command prompt as administrator,the first command line is C:\Windows\System32 that refers to Windows system folder (system directory) for 64-bit files,A 64-bit Windows has two different versions of the program files folder and the Windows system folder (system directory). One version is intended for 32-bit files and other version is intended for 64-bit files..you should set the system variables by using that path(that was said)